# Error saving barcode with elaphe running on debian, (related to ghostcript)

Tags: python, debian, ghostscript, elaphe

I am running this code in a debian/jessie box:

```
from elaphe import barcode
text = 'hello world in barcode'
bc = barcode('pdf417', text, options = dict(
         compact = False, eclevel = 5, columns = 13,
         rowmult = 2, rows = 3),
     margin=20, scale=1)
```

After running this, I execute the following:

```
bc.save('filename.png')
```

And then get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1653, in save   
  self.load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 336, in load
  self.im = Ghostscript(self.tile, self.size, self.fp, scale)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 143, in  Ghostscript
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__   
errread, errwrite) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child   raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] 
No such file or directory
```

If I run the same code in an ubuntu 14.04 box, there is no such error and works fine. Since I saw this error appearing in several post, and with lots of packages, I can conclude that it's something related to debian and not to the code itself, not even to elaphe python package.
It would be desirable to find if there is some kind of path to redefine or symlink somewhere, or if there is a patch for this.

Please help.

Comment: More info about the error:, even if I use cStringIO or StringIO, the error remains the same:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not super clean. But it might be caused by missing ghostscript package.

try:
sudo apt-get install ghostscript

Comment: Extremelly confuse... ghostcript was there, but with the installation everything was solved. Thankyou.